# siunitx: cannot define local symbol for \ohm

Tags: siunitx

To define localized unit symbols `siunitx` suggests using `\DeclareSIUnit`. It works well, except certain cases, like for example, `\ohm`. The error message is incomprehensible. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Libertinus Serif}

\DeclareSIUnit\ohm{\text{Ом}}

\begin{document}

«… а может быть, человек~— лишь промежуточное звено для создания истинного венца
творения~— рюмки коньяка с ломтиком лимона…»

\qty{10}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

It results in the following error message:

```
> \l__siunitx_symbol_tmpa_tl=macro:
->\mathrm {Ω}.
<argument> \show \l__siunitx_symbol_tmpa_tl 
                                 \show \l__siunitx_symbol_tmpb_tl \group_end: \
l.13 \begin{document}
                   
> \l__siunitx_symbol_tmpb_tl=macro:
->\mathrm {\protect \text  {Ом}}.
<argument> ...ymbol_tmpa_tl \show \l__siunitx_symbol_tmpb_tl 
                                                  \group_end: \prg_return_fa...
l.13 \begin{document}
```

What on earth it is supposed to mean? And what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a piece of stray debugging code in one release: you can just press Enter to get past it. The issue was only present in v3.0.11: it was not present in v3.0.10 and was fixed in v3.0.12.